# How can I calculate lines for a custom CartesianGrid in Rechart. How can I remap to the correct domain

Tags: recharts

CartesianGrid allows me to set the verticalPoints and horizontalPoints to be shown.

Unfortunately, these values are in pixel values on the chart, not in the coordiantes of the x and y domains.

I must be missing something.  I have an x-axis and a y-axis.  How can I map a value in those domains into positions on the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given some constants defining the chart:

```
const chartWidth = 600;      // width set on our chart object

const xAxisLeftMargin = 10;  // margins set on our chart object
const xAxisRightMargin = 20;
const xPadding = 0;          // padding set on both sides of xAxis

const yAxisWidth = 120;      // total widths of all yAxes
```

we can use d3 to create an xScale, like this:

```
const leftX = 0 + yAxisWidth + xAxisLeftMargin + xPadding;
const rightX = chartWidth - xPadding - xAxisRightMargin;
// note that rightX assumes there are no axes on the right hand side

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain(xDomain).range([leftX, rightX]);
```

Then assuming we have an array of verticalPoints:

`const verticalPoints: number[] = [];`

we just add values in the xDomain like this:

`verticalPoints.push(xScale(value))`

and we can render our vertical lines on the x-axis with the CartesianGrid like this:

`<CartesianGrid stroke="#d5d5d5" verticalPoints={verticalPoints} />`

Comment: What to do if Grid / Chart has no defined width (lives inside a Responsive Container)?

Comment: @olefrank use an event in the container to propagate the new width down to a component containing the Cartesian grid, and rebuild based on the new width.